# Dartium cannot find built in library

Tags: dart

I am trying to write an application that uses the RPC api.

My application works okay when run as javascript in chrome, but when I try and run it in Dartium, I get the following message

> The requested built-in library is not available on
>   Dartium.'package:rpc/src/context.dart': error: line 7 pos 1: library
>   handler failed import 'dart:io'; ^: package:rpc/src/context.dart

I don't think that my client code is importing dart:io. Is there any way of checking this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the RPC package code directly in your client application. RPC is server-side only. You can then generate the client code from your RPC server application. The README.md of the RPC package has more details how to do this.

Comment: Yes, i realise that. Trouble is that somewhere in my client code a dependency is pulling in the rpc/src/context.dart that then imports the dart.io. I was hoping there would be a easy way of determining what classes pulling which dependencies.

Comment: This is a known issue but AFAIK there is no good solution available yet.